# Deserialize JSON using Jackson with different types of object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to deserialize this payload:

```
{
   "commonField": {"a": "1234"},
   "X": {"c": "1234", "d": "5678"}
}
```

but "X" could be "Y" with a different definition.

My idea is having a DTO with the commonField and an Interface to be implemented by "X" or "Y".

I have been trying with JsonSubTypes but didn't work ([snippet](https://www.codepile.net/pile/1JbAVYxN))
Any idea?

Comment: SubTypes is the way to solve this problem. Can you please show what you have tried, so that we can help fix that implementation ?

Comment: How come a `key` can be dynamic?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar: something like that codepile.net/pile/1JbAVYxN

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
  "commonField": {"a": "1234"},
  "X": {"c": "1234", "d": "5678"}
}))
```

Comment: the idea is to use Jackson

Comment: Ah ok, sorry! I dont know about Jackson

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably deserialize to:

```
public class Payload {
    public CommonType commonField;
    public X x;
    public Y y;
}
```

Fields not present in the JSON will remain `null`.

**Edit**

> a single field with polymorphic content

You can achieve this with a few setters:

```
public class Payload {
    public CommonType commonField;
    private TheInterface polyField;

    public TheInterface getPolyField() {
        return polyField;
    }

    public void setX(X x) {
        polyfield = x;
    }

    public void setY(Y y) {
        polyfield = y;
    }
}
```

assuming that `X` and `Y` are declared to implement `TheInterface`.

Comment: That is the thing I want to avoid. I would like to have an unique field (Interface or superclass)

Comment: Don't forget to add ignoreUnknown annotation for unknow properties

Comment: @Toan: Since there are no unknown properties in this answer, I don't see why I would need that annotation?

Comment: @Crilofer: If you have additional constraints, you should add those to your question. And  what do you mean be "unique"? Did you mean a single field with polymorphic content that serializes from a different property depending on subtype?

Comment: @meriton: yes, a single field with polymorphic content